# How do I populate a table with an ajax request from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

With the following code I am able to populate a datatable table in below format using ajax request.

```
$("#example").DataTable({
ajax: {
            url: 'test.json',    
            dataSrc: 'dataset1'  
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "name"
            },
            {
                "data": "age"
            },
            {
                "data": "gender"
            }]
});
```

However how could I get the same result with a dataset as the one below?

```
{
  "DataSet2" : {
    "-L5_3n2zzOprYrfRRowd" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "age" : "42",
      "gender" : "M"
    },
    "-L5cf-S1s97ZHdy-0YeN" : {
      "name" : "Mathew",
      "age" : "39",
      "gender" : "M"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Below an update of what I am trying to get accomplished.
The data is different from the above but the idea is the same.
The below works for with a Json file as the shown below.

What I need however is to work with the same data but then from Firebase.
In firebase however each item has a push-key

The desired outcome should be like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20cT7.png)

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MK</title>
    <!-- DATATABLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- RESPONSIVENESS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
    <!-- DATETIMEPICKER -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
    <!-- DATATABLES FREE EDITOR -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.4/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    <!-- MYCSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input type='text' id="dateTime" class="dateTime" placeholder="Date Time" readonly>

    <div id='tableContainer'>

        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th><!-- COLUMN FOR RESPONSIVENESS -->
                    <th>INBOUND</th>
                    <th>ORG</th>
                    <th>STA</th>
                    <th>ETA</th>
                    <th>OUTBOUND</th>
                    <th>DES</th>
                    <th>STD</th>
                    <th>ETD</th>
                    <th>REMARKS</th>
                    <th>GATE</th>
                    <th>WHS</th>
                    <th>TEST</th>
                    <th>ARR</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>
<!-- FIREBASE -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- DATATABLES -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- RESPONSIVENESS -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<!-- DATETIMEPICKER -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- DATATABLES FREE EDITOR -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.4/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="datatablesAltEditor.js"></script>
<!-- MYJS -->
<script src="libs.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
    $("#example").DataTable({
    select: 'single',
    responsive: true,
    paging: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    order: [
        [3, 'asc']
    ],
    ajax: {
        url: 'dbs.json',
        dataSrc: 'dataset1'
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": null,
            defaultContent: '',
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false
        }, // RESPONSIVENESS
        {
            "data": "inbound"
        },
        {
            "data": "org"
        },
        {
            "data": "sta"
        },
        {
            "data": "eta"
        },
        {
            "data": "outbound"
        },
        {
            "data": "des"
        },
        {
            "data": "std"
        },
        {
            "data": "etd"
        },
        {
            "data": "remarks"
        },
        {
            "data": "gate"
        },
        {
            "data": "whs"
        },
        {
            "data": null,
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return data.flight + ' ' + data.org;
            }
        },
        {
            data: "arr"
        }
    ]
});
```

**JSON:**

```
{
"dataset1": [{
    "inbound": "MK509",
    "org": "ICN",
    "sta": "12DEC17 16:45",
    "eta": "12DEC17 17:35",
    "outbound": "MK509",
    "des": "ARN",
    "std": "12DEC17 18:45",
    "etd": "12DEC17 19:35",
    "remarks": "DELAYED",
    "gate": "S96",
    "whs": "T11",
    "arr": "X"
}, {
    "inbound": "RT8101",
    "org": "DOH",
    "sta": "12DEC17 08:25",
    "eta": "12DEC17 08:25",
    "outbound": "RT8101",
    "des": "ORD",
    "std": "12DEC17 10:25",
    "etd": "12DEC17 10:25",
    "remarks": "COW CHARTER",
    "gate": "S94",
    "whs": "T9",
    "arr": "X"
}],
"dataset2": [{
    "flight": "KIKKER1",
    "org": "ICN",
    "sta": "12DEC17 16:45",
    "eta": "12DEC17 17:35",
    "flight": "KE509",
    "des": "ARN",
    "std": "12DEC17 18:45",
    "etd": "12DEC17 19:35",
    "remarks": "DELAYED",
    "gate": "S96",
    "whs": "T11",
    "ciss": "X",
    "arr": "X"
}, {
    "flight": "KIKKER2",
    "org": "DOH",
    "sta": "12DEC17 08:25",
    "eta": "12DEC17 08:25",
    "flight": "QR8101",
    "des": "ORD",
    "std": "12DEC17 10:25",
    "etd": "12DEC17 10:25",
    "remarks": "COW CHARTER",
    "gate": "S94",
    "whs": "T9",
    "ciss": "X",
    "arr": "X"
}]
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you could get the keys using `Object.keys()` to get enumerable props of the object?

If your problem is that you don't know the key names?

Comment: @senojoeht, please excuse my ignorance. could you give me an example I am new to this...

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this is actually your problem, but if it's that you don't know the object keys you can find them with `Object.keys(yourObj)` which returns an array of strings (your object keys). You could then iterate over the object accessing the keys. Then fill the table. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: I checked the internet but could not find a similar example. Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code you have tried to get reference snapshot for DataSet2

Comment: @Himanshu, I was not able to produce any because I could not find a similar case. Now each object has a push key, but I don't know how to get the same result with a ajax request.

Comment: how did you output the json for dataset2 that you have posted. you can paste that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of columns. Get the child for each object and Loop over it using Object.keys() to get value at key. Finally push the data into columns array

```
let columns = [];
let data = [];
firebase.db().ref("DataSet2").once("value", function(snap){
    snap.forEach(snapshot => {
        Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(k => {
              columns.push(Object.assign({}, {"data":k}))
              data.push(Object.assign({}, {k:snapshot.val()[k]}))
        })
    })
})
console.log(columns)
console.log(data)
```

Now assign the columns and data to DataTable

```
$("#example").DataTable({
ajax: {
        url: 'test.json',    
        dataSrc: data 
      },
      "columns": columns
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hiamnshu, this gives me an array of all items. However, I need this information to be populated in a table, like in the example I gave in my first post. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok do one thing for me post the output of columns array and I will put it together to get what you have wanted. SO paste the output of `console.log(columns)`

Comment: I get an error ("missing } after property list") on the following line <br/>     `columns.push(Object.assign({}, {"data":k))`

Comment: Solved that one. Should be: \n `columns.push(Object.assign({}, {"data":k}))`

Comment: wow good one so my solutions works for you that a good thing. You can Accept my answer it works and upvote it

Comment: ok can you give me the reference of link from where you are using Data table so that I will know how to set data table in your case. Is [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) you wants to use right

Comment: The one you suggested will do. It doesn't really matter to me as long as the data from Fire base is correctly shown in the table

Comment: there is a process to accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Read the link

Comment: Yeah I know, I thought you were going to give me the last part of the solution. The part where all the data is populated in the table. Must have misread your previous post. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ok tell me where you stuck and edit your post. Show the error ok and image of what you got and what you wanted, in your post

Comment: I updated the question, I hope this clarifies what I am looking for